# Firebase Storage`uploadBytes`: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'byteLength')"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I'm trying to write a Firebase Cloud Function that uploads a file to Firebase Cloud Storage using `uploadBytes`. I'm following the [documentation for web apps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files). Whatever I do throws this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'byteLength')
```

This error message isn't listed on the [documentation page for error handling](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors) but I've deduced that the error message means that it can't find the file to upload. I'm getting this error with the emulator and with the cloud.

Let's start with `uploadString`, which works.

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytes, uploadString, connectStorageEmulator } from "firebase/storage";
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "12345",
    authDomain: "my-awesome-app.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://my-awesome-app.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "my-awesome-app",
    storageBucket: "my-awesome-app.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "12345",
    appId: "12345"
};
initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const StringMe = functions.firestore.document('StringMe/{userID}').onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const storage = getStorage();
    // const storageRef = ref(storage, 'message.txt'); // location to write to
    // connectStorageEmulator(storage, "localhost", 9199); // comment out to write to the cloud
    const storageRef = ref(storage, 'gs://my-awesome-app.appspot.com/Pictures/message.txt');
    const message = "Hello world!";

    async function uploadMessage() {
        try {
            await uploadString(storageRef, message);
            console.log("Uploaded a string!");
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    };

    return uploadMessage()
});
```

This uploads a string to my Cloud Firestore and  logs `Uploaded a string!` and then `Finished "StringMe" in 417.150521ms`. 60 seconds later it throws an error:

```
functions: Your function timed out after ~60s. To configure this timeout, see
      https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation.
⚠  Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.
```

That error seems to be a bug in the Firebase CLI, I ignore it.

Let's try this with the emulator. We'll comment out the `storageRef` and uncomment the two commented lines.

```js
const storageRef = ref(storage, 'message.txt');
connectStorageEmulator(storage, "localhost", 9199);
```

That doesn't throw any errors (except the 60 second timeout), doesn't log anything, and nothing is written to Storage. **Why doesn't the Storage Emulator work?**

Now let's make a file to upload.

```js
// my-module.js

export const file = "Hello world";
```

Then we'll upload it to Cloud Storage.

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytes, uploadString, connectStorageEmulator } from "firebase/storage";
import { file } from "./my-module.js";
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    databaseURL: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "...",
    appId: "..."
};
initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const ByteMe = functions.firestore.document('ByteMe/{userID}').onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const storage = getStorage(app);
    // const storageRef = ref(storage, 'hello.txt'); // location to write to
    // connectStorageEmulator(storage, "localhost", 9199); // comment out to write to the cloud
    const storageRef = ref(storage, 'gs://my-awesome-app.appspot.com/Pictures/hello.txt');

    const metadata = {
        contentType: 'text/plain',
    };

    async function uploadFile() {
        try {
            console.log(file);
            await uploadBytes(storageRef, file, metadata);
            console.log('Uploaded a file!');
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

    return uploadFile();
});
```

This logs `Hello world` (we know that the file is available and readable within the function) and then throws this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'byteLength')
```

Something is `undefined`. Nothing has changed in the code except that the string became `file`. The error message must be saying that it can't read the file. `byteLength` seems to be a red herring, best ignored unless you like rabbit holes. **Why can't `uploadBytes` read the file?**

Switching to the emulator throws the same error message.

Let's try getting a file from an API and then uploading it to Storage.

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytes, uploadString, connectStorageEmulator } from "firebase/storage";
import got from 'got';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    databaseURL: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "...",
    appId: "..."
};
initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const ByteAPI = functions.firestore.document('ByteAPI/{userID}').onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const storage = getStorage();
    // const storageRef = ref(storage, 'picture.jpg'); // location to write to
    // connectStorageEmulator(storage, "localhost", 9199); // comment out to write to the cloud
    const storageRef = ref(storage, 'gs://my-awesome-app.appspot.com/Pictures/winter.mp3');

    const metadata = {
        contentType: 'audio/mpeg',
    };

    async function uploadFile() {
        try {
            let file = await got('https://audio.oxforddictionaries.com/en/mp3/winter__us_2.mp3');
            await uploadBytes(storageRef, file, metadata);
            console.log('Uploaded a file!');
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

    return uploadFile();
});
```

You can click on https://audio.oxforddictionaries.com/en/mp3/winter__us_2.mp3 and listen to the audio file.

This throws the same error, with Cloud Storage or the emulator:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'byteLength')
```

I also tried uploading a `Uint8Array`, same error message. Is `uploadBytes` broken?

Comment: Can you try and check this [library](https://modularfirebase.web.app/common-use-cases/storage/#upload-a-file)?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Struggling for days here!

Comment: Yes, but I need to write a better answer. I'm working on this tutorial: https://github.com/tdkehoe/Cloud-Functions-for-Firebase-Tutorial The short answer is, use `uploadBytes` from the front end, not from Cloud Functions. Use Node in Cloud Functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer below works but is not best practices. I'm working on a best practices tutorial: https://github.com/tdkehoe/Cloud-Functions-for-Firebase-Tutorial. The short answer is, use uploadBytes from the front end, not from Cloud Functions. Use Node in Cloud Functions

--

I was able to download the audiofile from the Oxford English Dictionary API and upload it to Cloud Storage by changing `file` to `file['rawBody']`:

```js
await uploadBytes(storageRef, file['rawBody'], metadata);
```

This didn't work for uploading the `Hello world` text file. The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_from_a_blob_or_file) says that `uploadBytes` will handle "JavaScript File and Blob APIs". This has to do with JSON file and buffers, which I don't understand. I'll keep working on this.

Comment: This appears to be absolutely correct. It works as advertised in the browser, but not node - i.e. not in node based unit tests.